# Combining two GUID/UUIDs with MD5, any reasons this is a bad idea?

Tags: md5, guid, uuid

I am faced with the need of deriving a single ID from N IDs and at first a i had a complex table in my database with FirstID, SecondID, and a varbinary(MAX) with remaining IDs, and while this technically works its painful, slow, and centralized so i came up with this:

simple version in C#:

```
Guid idA = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid idB = Guid.NewGuid();

byte[] data = new byte[32];
idA.ToByteArray().CopyTo(data, 0);
idB.ToByteArray().CopyTo(data, 16);

byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(data);
Guid newID = new Guid(hash);
```

now a proper version will sort the IDs and support more than two, and probably reuse the MD5 object, but this should be faster to understand.

Now security is not a factor in this, none of the IDs are secret, just saying this 'cause everyone i talk to react badly when you say MD5, and MD5 is particularly useful for this as it outputs 128 bits and thus can be converted directly to a new Guid.

now it seems to me that this should be just dandy, while i may increase the odds of a collision of Guids it still seems like i could do this till the sun burns out and be no where near running into a practical issue.

However i have no clue how MD5 is actually implemented and may have overlooked something significant, so my question is this: is there any reason this should cause problems? (assume sub trillion records and ideally the output IDs should be just as global/universal as the other IDs)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you would not be generating a true UUID. You would end up with an arbitrary set of 128-bits. But a UUID is not an arbitrary set of bits. See the 'M' and 'N' callouts in [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Variants_and_versions). I don't know if this is a concern in practice or not. Perhaps you could manipulate a few bits (the 13th and 17th hex digits) inside your MD5 output to transform the hash outbut to a true UUID, as mentioned in [this description of Version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) UUIDs.

Another issue… [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) does not do a great job of distributing generated values across the range of possible outputs. In other words, some possible values are more likely to be generated more often than other values. Or as the Wikipedia article puts it, MD5 is not [collision resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistant).

Nevertheless, as you pointed out, probably the chance of a collision is unrealistic.

I might be tempted to try to increase the entropy by repeating your combined value to create a much longer input to the MD5 function. In your example code, take that 32 octet value and use it repeatedly to create a value 10 or 1,000 times longer (320 octects, 32,000 or whatever).

In other words, if working with hex strings for my own convenience here instead of the octets of your example, given these two UUIDs:

78BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1

FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C8

…instead of feeding this to the MD5 function:

78BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C8

…feed this:

78BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C878BC2A6B-4F03-48D0-BB74-051A6A75CCA1FCF1B8E4-5548-4C43-995A-8DA2555459C8

…or something repeated even longer.